# How to show a certain information for each option from my file?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to solve an exercise in which iI have to show informations like  **name of computer, type of processor and hard drive storage capacity** for every option(**computer**) in my forms and I have to show this information by using files. I did the forms but I don't know how to show a certain content or information from my file.

```
<html>
 <head>
     <title>Reading a file using PHP</title>
</head>

  <body>
     <form action="/action_page.php">
       <select name="computers">
       <option value="ASUS">ASUS - TUF FX705GM 17.3" Gaming L 
       aptop</option>
       <option value="Lenovo">Lenovo - Legion Y530 15.6" Gaming 
        Laptop</option>
        <option value="MSI">MSI - 15.6" Gaming Laptop</option>
        <option value="Dell">Dell - G7 15.6" Gaming Laptop</option>
        </select>
         <br><br>
        <input type="submit">
         </form> 

             <?php
              $filename = "tmp.txt";
              $file = fopen( $filename, "r" );
                ?>

    </body>
```

**My file is empty right now**

I expect that the output will show me the `list of my computers` and when I `choose one` and submit, it will show me the information of this computer, i.e., name of computer, type of processor and hard drive storage capacity.

Comment: Is the file CSV? If so take a look at [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: no, it's txt. but if it's necessary i  can change it into CSV .